# My data from my model is not showing up on my webpage through templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to show the data on the webpage but I am not able to figure out why the data is not populated on the webpage

my model is this

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    staffid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
        
    def staff_name(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.firstname, self.lastname)
        
    def get_absolute_url(self): # new
        return reverse('staffdetail', args=[str(self.staffid)])
```

my views for this is

```
class StaffListView(ListView):
    model = Staff
    template_name = 'staffview.html'
```

and the template is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p><a href="{% url 'staffnew' %}">Add a new Staff member</a></p>

{% if staff %}
    There are {{ staff|length }} records:
    {% for s in staff %}
        <div class="client-entry">
        <p><a href="{% url 'staffdetail'%}">{{ s.staffid }}</a></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    There are no staff in the system
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

---

The output on the web page just gives me the else statement. I checked in Django admin and found that there is data in the staff table. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

The urls.py file is

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView, ClientListView, ClientCreateView, ClientDetailView, ClientUpdateView, ClientDeleteView, ProjectCreateView, ProjectDetailView, StaffListView, StaffCreateView, StaffDetailView, StaffUpdateView, StaffDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path('staffview/<int:pk>/staffdetail/staffdelete', StaffDeleteView.as_view(), name='staffdelete'),
    path('staffview/<int:pk>/staffdetail/staffupdate', StaffUpdateView.as_view(), name='staffupdate'),
    path('staffview/<int:pk>/staffdetail', StaffDetailView.as_view(), name='staffdetail'),
    path('staffview/staffnew', StaffCreateView.as_view(), name='staffnew'),
    path('staffview/', StaffListView.as_view(), name='staffview'),
    path('client/<int:pk>/projectexisting/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='projectdetail'),
    path('projectexisting/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='projectdetail'),
    path('client/<int:pk>/projectnew/', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='projectnew'),
    path('client/<int:pk>/delete/', ClientDeleteView.as_view(), name='clientdelete'),
    path('client/<int:pk>/update/', ClientUpdateView.as_view(), name='clientupdate'),
    path('client/<int:pk>/', ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='clientdetail'),
    path('client/new/', ClientCreateView.as_view(), name='clientnew'),
    path('clientview/', ClientListView.as_view(), name='clientview'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

Comment: Did the answer below solved your problem?

Comment: No, i started getting a no reverse match error.

Comment: Update the your post and include your `urls.py` file.

Comment: updated the post with the urls file

Comment: Try updating this line `model = Staff` to `model = Staff.objects.all()` and add `context_object_name = "staff"`

Comment: Well i guess i get the same error
NoReverseMatch at /staffview/1/staffdetail
Reverse for 'staffupdate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['staffview/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/staffdetail/staffupdate$']

Comment: What page are you seeing this error for `/staffview/1/staffdetail`? That seems to me you're trying to access the details view and not the list view... Which of the views are you trying to work with here?

Comment: I am trying to create a system where first the page will show a list view of all staff. Then on clicking the link on the list view, the page should redirect to detail view of that staff where I can update/delete that staff information

Comment: The page is when i add a new staff - path('staffview/staffnew', StaffCreateView.as_view(), name='staffnew'),

Comment: Since `StaffCreateView` is where you are getting the error, then you should probably update the question and include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
class StaffListView(ListView):
        model = Staff
        template_name = 'staffview.html'
        context_object_name = "staff"
```

Comment: on adding context_object_name = "staff", i get another error which says - 
NoReverseMatch at /staffview/
Reverse for 'staffdetail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['staffview/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/staffdetail$']

Comment: `{% url 'staffdetail' staff.id %}`?

Comment: The URL will take me to details of that staff member and I will be able to either update or delete their information
```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="client-entry">
        <p>{{ staff.staffid }}</p>
        <p>{{ staff.staff_name }}</p>
        <p>{{ staff.phonenumber }}</p>
    </div>

<p><a href="{% url 'staffupdate' %}">Update Staff information</a></p>
<p><a href="{% url 'staffdelete' %}">Delete Staff information</a></p>
    
{% endblock content %}
```